# How to deal with failing ideas?

Tags: publications, research-process, postdocs, computer-science, research-topic

I graduated from my PhD last November and as I get along super well with my PhD supervisors, I decided to pursue research with them on my free time alongside my postdoctoral position.

We all have spent a large amount of working time (I can't say if it's months or years!) to make an idea concrete.

However, things did not go as planned.

Numerical experiments of our work shows that it can only remain theoretical.

Most specifically, our model works for very tiny instances (up to 15 nodes, in graph theory) and can not scale up at all. It already takes between one hour and two hours to solve such instances.

For real life size instances (starting at 50 nodes), the model would take far longer than hours to solve.

How should we proceed with such failing idea?

As my professor wanted me to think of a detailed plan of action, here are my thoughts to be improved, corrected and completed:

A theoretical model is still interesting to publish as eventually, computers performances will improve over time and maybe this model will serve on real life instances some day. Still this is disappointing to say it cannot scale up. Maybe some other researches will find ideas to make it applicable once it has been published?
Another possibility is to try improving the theoretical model but how could we know if this would last six months or 10 more years? We are currently out of ideas to make the model better after having tested a tons of ideas (some of them improved the model performances by 10%, some small ideas were thrown up, etc.)
A final possibility is to give up the research we conducted but to me, this is unacceptable with respect to the amount of quality work on this research topic. This is a year a half of my thesis and several months after.

Comment: Have you consulted with an algorithms expert?  Does your model require solving an NP-hard problem?  The right computer scientist could perhaps tell *why* your model is slow without even touching a computer.  That might inform next steps.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo, thank you for your comment. I believe my professor is an algorithm expert. Indeed we are solving a NP-Hard problem, we are working with knowledges on computer science and operations research. This is an interesting suggestion to ask for another expert's opinion

Comment: After further thought - I'm voting to close - an answer to this question strongly depends on the norms and values of your research community.  If you were a pure mathematician aiming for a job at a top research university, my advice would be to shelve this work as this kind of paper would have zero or even negative value (and every pure mathematician has file cabinets full of failed projects), but an applied mathematician aiming for a job at a middling research university would probably disagree.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I strongly disagree with your suggestion to close, since I think folks run into this sort of dilemma frequently. I'd suggest that you put your advice in an answer instead.

Comment: @jakebeal: I just don't see how this question can have one answer - it requires a few hundred answers, one for each combination of field (sometimes subfield), country, and for some countries type of university.  Academia varies too much here for a useful answer.

Comment: In my field months of computing hours are common, why is it a problem in your field that it can take many hours or days to solve real life size instances? Ps: I suggest you to make your question more concise, I don't see why your relationship with your previous supervisors matters to the question.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: *this question strongly depends on the norms and values of your research community* – … and as such it is on-topic here, because it is about the norms and values of academia (as opposed to the content of research). Sure, at the end of the day, the asker needs to evaluate whether further pursuing this path is worth the effort. But that’s exactly what the question is about (in my understanding): how to make the decision and not what to decide.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/what-to-do-when-you-spend-several-months-working-on-an-idea-that-fails-in-a-mast/31082#31082

Comment: Have you tried to "cut through the Gordian know" by making one radical simplifying assumption? e.g. certain shared properties across nodes, self-similarity, and such, to radically reduce computational time. Then go for a "proof of concept" angle.

Comment: Initially I thought this question too much like a help-me-crack-my-thesis-problem to be on SE Academia. 3 others apparently share this view and voted to close. But it's not really about that. It's more a how do I get this thesis topic wrapped and out of my head sort of question. This is not uncommon in real academia, I feel.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You did not have a failing idea. You just had an idea that did not scale (if I understood you correctly). These are two *very different* things.

Your approach brings a model to the table and a proof-of-concept study. That's the novelty. Maybe at some point, it is possible to scale it, via better computers, clever classical or quantum algorithms or possibly suitable approximations or probabilistic algorithms that do not guarantee results 100%.

There are instances where there is a cool idea that scales horribly, and then, after some time, people find excellent, and highly performative algorithms that scale much better; maybe with some compromise, such as approximation, random sampling or other. I know of a model for which no good approximation for around 6 years was known, scaling horribly, for which no obvious route to improvement was conceivable. The following years saw a spate of reasonable, if not gargantuan improvements. 15 years later a highly effective and elegant approximation was discovered. This is a very *fast* rate of improvement.

Even in the well-known realm of matrix multiplication, the naive O(n^3) algorithm can be substantially improved (I believe it's around O(n^2.372) now.

In short, the fact that it cannot be computed now, does not mean it cannot be computed in the future. If you have an interesting question, model and theory, it's definitely worth publishing.

Comment: Matrix multiplication may not be the best analogy, since all the fancy recent bounds are purely theoretical AFAIK.

Comment: The last paragraph is unknown here - there could be known theoretical reasons why this cannot be computed, ever.  Assuming P<>NP, there are indeed theoretical bounds on how well and how quickly solutions to NP-hard problems can be approximated.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: Indeed, they're "galactic algorithms", only faster with ridiculous problem sizes. Strassen's is useful in practice (n>100). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication#Strassen's_algorithm , O(n^2.807).  Same with BigInt multiply: [Did the 2019 discovery of O(N log(N)) multiplication have a practical outcome?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/1414) - no, Toom-Cook and Schönhage-Strassen are still the best practical algorithms for big problem sizes that fit on real computers (at least that anyone's interested in actually computing.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Of course, but for instance Shannon codes show that you may have excellent feasible approximations where the asymptotically precise calculation is galactic. The point is that, in general, you do not know if all good complexity calculations are galactic.

Comment: Even things that don't scale can have value.  For example, the typical person wanting a [traveling salesman solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is looking to optimize a couple dozen stops at most.

Comment: Interestingly, TSP can actually be solved for much bigger problems than required in practice. For example “shortest path to visit all US cities with a population over 100,000”. This can be solved but the tour will take weeks or months.

Comment: Your answer: "you didn't have a failing idea, you had an idea that can't scale nowadays" and @jakebeal's answer: "you should publish your bad idea and move on" are the two answers' I would like to tick. I choose yours because it made me realise our idea, in a sense, could be a good idea some day. Since I posted my question, we have continued to improve the model. It still doesn't scale. Having in mind that the fact it doesn't scale doesn't make it a bad idea helped me a lot on continuing working on it. I hope that soon, my former director will say we can submit this work :)

Answer (score 33):

**Negative results are still results!**

In my career, I've had a lot of ideas that have worked out, and also a lot of ideas that have not worked out. But when you've spent a lot of time on a project, you've almost always learned some things, even if they weren't the things you hoped for. Share that knowledge with others!

I always think that the saddest possible fate for a piece of work you've poured a lot of time and effort into is to have it die quietly in the dark. Instead, you can at least write a paper as a grave marker to mourn its passing:

> Let me tell you about the life of my friend, Nifty New Graph Model (NNGM). NNGM was a bright and promising idea, full of energy and wanting to help people with [relevant application here].  When NNGM was young, it seemed full of promise, all the way up to around 15 nodes. But as it scaled, everything seemed to go wrong. And when we did tests, we got the fatal diagnosis: Bad Big O. Well, we knew then that NNGM didn't have the future we'd all hoped for, and so we're putting it into cryogenic storage. But we wanted to tell its story here: maybe others can learn from our experiences, or maybe even figure out how to cure NNGM's problems and bring it out of storage in the future.

Silly? A little, maybe, but I find that publishing a story like this (in more professional language, of course) really helps me to let go and move on. You won't put it in a glamour journal, but there's always solid society-level publications or megajournals that are happy to accept results that are true but not exciting.

And sometimes these articles really can be helpful to others too! Some of my own "gravestone" publications have dozens of citations, clearly having picked up an afterlife that I had never envisioned for them.

**Bottom line: publish the sad things that you've learned, and then move on.**

Comment: +1. This is a vital idea. Research isn't to prove our initial guesses but to arrive at knowledge and truth. Knowing something doesn't work can be as (more) important than knowing it does. Hydroxychloroquine.

Comment: In theoretical mathematics, if you are aiming for a research-oriented job, then I think writing this up is at best a waste of time.  Researchers who have several such papers in fact LOSE prestige for this work - people wonder why they're wasting their time with it.  And - no - the research community doesn't gain from the paper because we just won't find it; I still think there's a good chance that a determinantal identity that would solve the conjectures in my dissertation is in some 19th century paper somewhere, but no one will ever find it.

Comment: I agree @AlexanderWoo. Negative results are not usually published in mathematics (though I agree with Captain Emacs on the nature of this work). They're at best a good candidate for something in a blog post, but most mathematicians don't keep up a math blog, so it is likely not to gain any real attention.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo  What the hell is *theoretical mathematics* ? You sure it's not theoretical physics that you mean ?

Comment: @Trunk - as opposed to applied mathematics.  Some of us are staying away from the term 'pure mathematics' because the notion of 'purity' has unfortunate historical connotations (that are in fact historically related to the origins of the usage of the term 'pure mathematics').

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Which may be true but is actually quite idiotic. So OP and his colleagues had this great idea which didn’t work out. If nobody writes it down, it will still look like a great idea, and the next guy will look at it, and waste another year of time. And another one in two years time.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I see no *unfortunate historical connotations* that grown adults can't easily negotiate. Maybe you can link us to an elaboration on this or another SE post ? As you will appreciate, of its very nature, mathematics is initially abstract and hence "theoretical" in the sense of it not being experimental/practical, at least at the outset of a new math concept; though within a generation most math concepts find application in the working world or its support technologies. I'm not sure we should move away from established terms and their translations in other languages also perhaps.

Comment: @gnasher729 - the math literature is so big and so unsearchable (because the same ideas are known by many names or no name at all, and it can take weeks of work to realize two ideas are actually the same) that the next person will never find the paper anyway.  Most math papers are never read by anyone other than the peer reviewers.  Adding more papers doesn't help the situation.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo You can say the same thing about lots of different fields. Doesn't mean we shouldn't publish anything but good results.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo What's worse, two ideas may be effectively equivalent, but the insight that they are may be nonobvious or even really deep. But it would be great if there were a LLM-like search engine for math for statements that appear at least shallowly equivalent.

Answer (score 11):

Generally if there is a good method that doesn't scale well, it is sometimes possible to develop a scalable algorithm that approximates the method well. Of course you can collaborate with people who have the expertise for this, but even without such a thing, I think that a publication is realistic that in its conclusion clearly says that right now scalability is an issue and finding an approximation that improves scalability is a worthwhile project for future research. This may not fly in a strong impact journal, but there are many journals that would be keen to publish something that is original, correct, and presented with insight even if scalability is an issue. I have seen such papers. And somebody may later dig it out and develop a better algorithm or do something new inspired by this.

Comment: Something that I forgot to mention in my question is that my former PhD director nearly only publish on top journals with high impact and, if I understood their working habits well, would not let our work to be submitted to a "middle" journal and will continue try to make the model as good as possible

Comment: @JKHA Well, if you can get it into a top journal, fine. If you can't, but are personally interested in having it published at a somewhat lower level (for a fresh PhD with academic ambitions every publication counts), better than making assumptions talk with them!

Answer (score 9):

First, stop berating yourself! You worked hard, you achieved a result ... and you have discovered the limits to which your results can be applied with current technology or, perhaps, pushed using current methods.

This is how much of mathematics proceeds. The work is incremental. One need only look at the [history](https://doi.org/10.1109%2FMASSP.1984.1162257) of the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) algorithm to see that it took 160 years to get from Gauss's initial approach to the [Cooley-Tukey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) [publication](https://doi.org/10.2307%2F2003354) in 1965. Tukey and Cooley had the significant advantage of having at their disposal a object that only came into being around 1940 ... a computer! Prior to that, the possibility of applying the FFT to siginficant problems was largely beyond reach ... the same scaling issue as is staring at you. Should Gauss have been embarrassed?

Consider also the [paper](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0273-0979-07-01168-8) by Terrence Tao on what constitutes good mathematics in which he presents a very incomplete list and even then, concludes "As the above list demonstrates, the concept of mathematical quality is a high-dimensional one and lacks an obvious canonical total ordering."

My advice: if you have not already done so, consult with someone who is an expert in relevant algorithms; they might have an insight that would lead to an improvement in scaling. But then, irrespective of the outcome of the consultation, write up what you have without feeling that it was a failed idea. Then move on.

Appendix: As an aside, although I have put in references to the history of the FFT, a more personal view is evident in the paper by Cooley that you can find [here](https://faculty.uml.edu/cbyrne/FFT.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, thank your lucky stars for having a sympathetic research milieu. Few enjoy such bounties.

Others have clarified the need to publish what you have (originally at least) done, regardless of its limitations as a tool with a practical future.

The question of where to go from here with this is the one I'll answer.

Regardless of whether you intend to have another crack at this matter, i.e. to devise a new model or to seek ways to make the existing one more computation-efficient, I think your conscious mind needs a rest from this topic right now.

A change is as good as a rest, they say. And looking at other topics and their challenges may well throw up the odd idea on how to advance the old intractable one.

Sometimes it is only when we accept "defeat" with a challenge that our mind is freed of those trammelled patterns of thought that led us nowhere and the real path forward starts to dawn on us.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the result of your research is that you have indeed solved a mathematical problem, just that it is not applicable to real life scenarios.

Are you aware that most of what makes our computers work, is based on papers from the '50s when it was also entirely unfeasible to make practical use of them ?

So my suggestion is to publish. You don't know what the future brings.