# Writing a B.Sc. thesis with only failed results

Tags: thesis, writing, bachelor

I'm writing my B.Sc thesis about analysing coin cell batteries that I made by hand. Most of them give off voltage when I test them with a multimeter, but when I try to do a formation cycle I get bad voltage data. My thesis is a further analysis; working batteries is just a expectation. Therefore I don't really have anything to analyse. My supervisor isn't much help and I'm running out of time to try again.

Is it possible to write a good thesis using only these bad/failed results? How would one go about doing it?

edit:
i was given pouch cell batteries and told to make them into coin cells becuase the test rig only works with coin cells.

The research question is "Investiagion of DVA (differential voltage analysis) as a measure to predict self discharge in batteries". So if the problem was that i couldnt find a connection between self discharge and DVA i would know what to do. But since the batteries aren't even working it feels like i havent even begun to experiment.

My result would "just be" "I couldn't find a connection because the batteries didnt work" haha. I hope that explains the situation better

Comment: Particularly for an undergraduate thesis, the point is more in doing some work and analyzing it (and writing it up) than what the results actually are. So, you will spend more time (and writing) on what you measured and why it is not what you expected.

Comment: @BryanKrause This is the first time i'm using stack exchange so i dont know if this is normal etiquette. I added some information to clarify

Comment: @Buffy added some info to clarify

Comment: Editing your post to add clarification in response to comments is exactly the correct thing to do in the Stack Exchange model, thank you.

Comment: What does your supervisor say if you ask them just this? Who decides about the grade of your work, and what role does your supervisor have in this (this is different in different places; sometimes the supervisor is the most or even the only important person)?

Comment: @ChristianHennig I've been told to just keep trying, its just that time is running out. I dont think he has anything to do with the grading, but he will help with defending it

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/30995/what-to-do-when-you-spend-several-months-working-on-an-idea-that-fails-in-a-mast/31082#31082

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes research doesn't go well. Usually persistence is required along with being flexible and changing plans, but it may not be possible to go through all the necessary iterations in the limited time available for, say, an undergraduate student.

It's unfortunate your supervisor is not more helpful, this is exactly the circumstance you need them. I would make sure you've asked them for very specific guidance, though, don't ask "what should I do ?" be sure to ask exactly the question you pose here about writing the thesis.

Without other guidelines I can give the two options I would give my own mentee. One option would be to pivot and write a thesis about modifying batteries. Explain what you tried and exactly how it failed. Think of your audience as your past self: how would you help yourself know everything you've learned before you get started.

The other would be to write a hypothetical paper where you write your introduction and methods exactly as you normally would, but when you get to the results present possible ways the data could have come out and how you would interpret those results. Include the result you might have expected as well as alternatives that would be plausible if your assumptions were wrong. You can even prepare simulated data and figures to practice those steps.

You can also combine these approaches.

Remember that this project is mostly to 1) expose you to research and 2) show you've learned to present results the way scientists do. You don't need actual research results to achieve the second goal; by trying and struggling you've made excellent progress towards the first as well.

All that said, it's also possible that your efforts so far are insufficient. If you put in the time and work then you shouldn't be penalized for struggling. But, if you tried to put something together last minute or waited too long to get help it's possible this cannot be salvaged satisfactorily. I don't think this actually fits your situation but I unfortunately have direct experience with undergrads who disappeared after an initial consultation and then showed up when their paper was due wanting to know what to write. Yikes.

Comment: Thank you. This has given me the right mindset to continue. I think the hypotethical approach will work and i already have some ideas about how to start it. Again thanks a lot

Comment: @Markus See also the comment by Christian above; if the supervisor is not who grades/assesses your thesis you should contact whoever is.